# Use a repository, event or service provider here?

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I have this function in an `UploadController`, which is used to cancel an upload, and I am trying to improve it.

This `"File::delete..block"` exists twice in my application. Would it for example make sense to exclude this block from the controller? And if yes, what should I use, `Repository`, `Service Provider` or an `Event`?

```
public function postDelete(Request $request)
{
    $filename = $request->input('filename');

    $upload = Upload::where('filename',$filename)->where('accepted',0)->firstOrFail();

    File::delete('img/uploads/'.$filename.'_o.jpg');
    File::delete('img/uploads/'.$filename.'.jpg');
    File::delete('img/uploads/'.$filename.'_zoom.jpg');
    File::delete('img/uploads/'.$filename.'_tn.jpg');
    File::delete('img/uploads/'.$filename.'_250.jpg');
    File::delete('img/uploads/'.$filename.'_50.jpg');

    $upload->delete();

    Cache::forget('waiting_uploads');

    $msg = 'upload has been deleted';
    Mail::to('xyz@xxx.tld')->send(new TextMail($msg));

    return redirect('upload');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put that in a service that calls a repository. That way your controller does not interact with a data-layer object and everything is separated cleanly.